# Adding Product Programmatically to Cart Issue

Tags: magento-1, event-observer

I am on the product page. I have a bundle product and when I press the `add to cart` button I want to add a simple product programmatically to cart. 
I'm using this event: `checkout_cart_product_add_after` for my observer.

This is my code:

```
    public function cartProductUpdateAfter($observer)
    {
        $this->cartProductAddAfter($observer);
    }
    public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $productToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productToAdd->load(1745);

        $this->_addProductToCart($productToAdd, 1);
    }
    protected function _addProductToCart($product, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        if ($product->getId()) {
            // infinite loop probably
            $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm getting a maxium execution time exceeded error message, problably because it calls itself. Can you give me some ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace last function with this:

```
   protected function _addProductToCart($product, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if ($product->getId()) {
            // infinite loop probably
            $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
            $cart->save();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```